# Linux + how to simulate JBOD disks that are out of service in shelf

Tags: rhel, kernel, disk, scsi, dmidecode

We have Kafka machines installed with RHEL 7.2 servers on Dell HW and a shelf includes 15 disks.

We want to understand what happens when we push out one of the Kafka disks, and see if Kafka is still functional.

So the easy solution is just to push out the disk from the shelf.

But is it possible to simulate this situation without pushing out the disk?

For example we can umount the disks from the mount point, but this isn't enough good like pushing out the disks from the shelf.

Comment: It's going to depend on whether you're using RAID or if it's JBOD with Kafka handling the disk redundancy

Comment: we have JBOD , and from df we can see  all 15 disks

Comment: How is the shelf connected to the server(s)? Direct SATA/SAS or something else like iSCSI or FibreChannel? Is it one shelf for one server, or are there more servers than shelves? It sounds like there is just one filesystem on each disk, is it so? Then within the Kafka configuration, how are the Kafka log directories arranged to the disks? Are you using a topic replication factor greater than the default 1? Which `acks` setting are your Kafka producers using?

Comment: I think our shelf are Direct SAS ( but for sure not FibreChannel )